# What font does Google Chrome address bar use?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, typeface

What font does Google Chrome address bar use?

If it matters, here are the specifications of what I am using:

```
Google Chrome 5.0.322.2 (Official Build 38810) unknown
WebKit 533.1
V8 2.1.0.1
User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)
AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.322.2 Safari/533.1
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Windows XP, Windows Server 2008 R2: *Tahoma*
- Vista and 7: *Segoe UI*
- GNOME Shell: *Cantarell*
- Mac OS X: *Lucida Grande*

Comment: @skelly: where did you get to know this from?

Comment: Tahoma and Segoe UI are the system-wide interface fonts on XP and Vista/7 respectively.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahoma_(typeface) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe

Comment: What is the "system-wide interface font" for Fedora?

Comment: Chrome on Mac OS doesn't seem to still use Lucida Grande. At least the comparison I did doesn't match.

Comment: depends on the version... it uses the system font, which is San Francisco as of El Capitan, but Lucida Grande for earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to note that, it can be changed in "Window Color and Appearance" window. 
Also you have to choose "Message box" in the item list, first.
Hope this is useful ;)